# How to get trained model with weights values in JSON file in tensorflow?

Tags: json, tensorflow

I need all trained parameters in JSON file. So that it can be readable and can be used for inference elsewhere.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular *[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)*?

Answer (score 1):

Not a problem.  Here is an [example python code](https://github.com/panchishin/learn-to-tensorflow/blob/master/solutions/04-xor-2d.py) that trains a NN to solve the XOR problem and then displays all the parameters.

Example output

```
m1
[[-5.18443155  2.54194689 -5.21277475]
 [ 2.2101481  -5.4731164  -5.83126402]]

b1
[-0.34876832 -0.57951623  1.53269577]

m2
[[-3.68808436  4.98799658]
 [-3.78472781  4.89942074]
 [ 4.83149099 -3.83740902]]

b2
[ 2.53572464 -1.26663828]

y_out
[[ 0.98557901  0.01442094]
 [ 0.96264613  0.03735387]
 [ 0.0257617   0.97423834]
 [ 0.02632448  0.97367555]]
```

Line 47 `results = sess.run([m1,b1,m2,b2,y_out,loss])` extracts all the weights from the TF graph.  Instead of printing them you can easily convert that to JSON using Pythons JSON function like so

**Add line 54:**

```
    import json
    print json.dumps(result.tolist())
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am actually concerned about dumping weights in json for CNN. Specially for the sequential model in keras.